# jQuery Validation Plugin, Unbind Single Rule?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

is there  way to unbind a rule in jquery validator?

**suppose I have:**

```
$('#myform').validate({
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true
                }
            }
        })
```

What I want is that when I finish the validation it must unbind field 2.

Comment: try this $(<#field2 id>).rules("remove", "required");

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup of your form?

Comment: I don't understand the point of removing the rule after validation.  What's the idea behind that?

Comment: When a user choses to send aditional data you must show those fields and bind validations to them so that they cannot be send without being validated, when the user unchecks or deicides not to send that fields the app must unbind those validations to let it pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
        field1: {
            required: true
        },
        field2: {
            required: true
        }
    }
})
```

You would use [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) to remove all validation rules from your specified input.

```
$('input[name="field2"]').rules('remove')
```

I'm not sure I understand why you need to remove the rule after successful validation, but you could test the form programatically using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/), and then remove the rule.

```
if ($('#myform').valid()) {    // if the form is valid
    $('input[name="field2"]').rules('remove');  // then remove the rules
}
```

`.valid()` will immediately test the form and return a boolean `true` or `false` depending on validation status.

Answer (score 0):

Use $("#field2").rules("remove", "required")

```
$("#commentForm").validate({
 rules: {
    field1: {
        required: true
    },
    field2: {
        required: true
    }

 }
});

//To remove rule after submitting it will be removed
$('#commentForm').submit(function () {
  $(this).validate();
  $("#field2").rules("remove", "required");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Af9a9/3/

Comment: You're making a big assumption that the OP has an `id` attribute on the input and it shares the same value as the `name` attribute. You should be very clear that your code will only work as long as the OP's input contains attribute `id="field2"`.  Also, calling `.validate()` a second time inside the submit handler does absolutely nothing.  The `.validate()` method is always ignored after its first initialization.

Comment: I just showed the way how to unbind the validation and after all id is just an selector at any time you can change selector according to requirement.
btw thanks for this extra information.